# Conditional Join in DB2

Tags: join, db2, case, condition

2 tables are given

Table T_PRICE

```
P_Price    P_Type    P_Route
15         red       long
10                   long
5                    small
```

Table T_ROUTE

```
R_Type     R_Route
blue       long
red        long
black      small
```

I need to display all Routes with prices.
When there is no price for type, price should be from table T_PRICE without type.

My approach:

```
Select * from T_ROUTE
left outer join T_PRICE on P_Route = R_Route 
and case when P_Type <> R_Type then '' else R_Type end = P_Type
```

Wrong Result:

```
R_Type R_Route  P_Price P_Type P_Route
blue   long     NULL    NULL   NULL
red    long     15      red    long
black  small    NULL    NULL   NULL
```

Right result should be:

```
R_Type R_Route  P_Price P_Type P_Route
blue   long     10             long
red    long     15      red    long
black  small    5              small
```

How do I get the conditional join to work?
Thank you!..

Answer (score 1):

You need two joins here, one with the "matching" type set, another with "default" type.

I'm making two assumptions:

- "Missing" `p_type` is an empty string, not null, as follows from your query.
- There is at most one row in `t_price` for each `p_route` and empty `p_type`.

:

```
select r_route, r_type, coalesce(match.p_price, dflt.p_price)
from t_route
left outer join t_price match 
  on (r_route, r_type) = (match.p_route, match.p_type)
left outer join t_price dflt
  on r_route = dflt.p_route and dflt.p_type = ''
```

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=a073d8e285769820e1ea52c335943fb5) <sub>(It would be nice if you'd included it yourself).</sub>